# difference between (double)(1/2) and (double)1/2 in java

Tags: java, casting, double

I want to know the difference between

```
System.out.print((double)1/2);
System.out.print((double)(1/2));
```

The first answer I got was  0.5, but the second one gives 0.0 .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(double)(1/2)` first computes `1/2`, which results in `0` (int division), and then casts the result to `double` (which gives `0.0`).

`(double)1/2` first casts `1` to `double` and then divides `1.0` by `2` (floating point division), resulting in `0.5`. This is equivalent to `1.0/2` or `1/2.0`.

Comment: Was going to answer the same thing! Very nice and short answer!

Comment: thanks that explains alot .

Comment: Beat me to it :) Nice answer!

Comment: or `1.0/2.0` for completion sake ;)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the operator precedence and type promotion. In the case (double)1/2, 1 is casted to double and divided by 2 after promotion of the int 2 to double 2.0, i.e., a double division is calculated. In the case (double)(1/2) an integer division is executed and thus the result is 0, which is afterwards casted to double, i.e., 0.0.

Comment: Operator precedence, not preference :)

Comment: oops, corrected

Answer (score 1):

`(double) (1/2)`, where `(1/2)` is evaluated to `0`, because 1 and 2 are integers and the decimal is truncated. The `1/2` is evaluated first.

`(double) 1/2` is the same as `((double)1)/2`, which will return a double answer so the decimal will not be truncated.